# set up Ubercart for combo meal

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, ubercart

building a lunch ordering system and looking to apply a discount when the user buys a soup and pairs with a sandwich. ive looked into a few different ways of doing this and am looking for some input. Thinking it might be easiest to apply the discount as a conditional action within the shopping cart. this seems much more streamlined than building a separate engine to combine before adding to cart.

thoughts / advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional action is usually the way to go for that stuff

Answer (score 0):

Just an aside...I'm not sure if Drupal is best solution for rapid order entry system required for a lunch counter.

Comment: yup but its being bolted onto an existing Drupal site with a robust userbase